# Python - Press the key to zoom in and out (overlap)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to add a function to enlarge and reduce the picture. The function I put in now is not the function I want. I want to add a function that magnifies continuously when I press the key.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter.simpledialog import *

def pen():
  global name
  name = askopenfilename(parent = window, filetypes = (("GIF", "*.gif"),
            ("All files", "*.*")))
  photo = PhotoImage(file = name)
  pLabel.configure(image = photo)
  pLabel.image = photo

value = 0

def Exit():
    window.quit()
    window.destroy()

def key_up(event): 
   photo = PhotoImage(file = name)
   photo = photo.zoom(3,3)
   pLabel.configure(image = photo)
   pLabel.image = photo

def key_Down(event):  
   photo = PhotoImage(file = name)
   photo = photo.subsample(3,3)
   pLabel.configure(image = photo)
   pLabel.image = photo

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("zoom in and out")

photo = PhotoImage()
pLabel = Label(window, image = photo)
pLabel.pack(expand = 1, anchor = CENTER)

mainMenu = Menu(window)
window.config(menu = mainMenu)

fileMenu = Menu(mainMenu)
mainMenu.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label = 'Open File', command = pen)
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label = 'exit', command = Exit)

window.bind("<Up>",key_up)
window.bind("<Down>",key_Down)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more complicated.  You will need to set a flag on key press, and clear the flag on key release, and use a timed callback to do the zooms.  This will do 10 steps per second.  I might have up/down swapped from your intent.

```
zooming = False

def zoom_in(event): 
    if not zooming:
        return
    photo = PhotoImage(file = name)
    photo = photo.zoom(3,3)
    pLabel.configure(image = photo)
    pLabel.image = photo
    window.after( 10, zoom_in )

def zoom_out(event):  
    if not zooming:
        return
    photo = PhotoImage(file = name)
    photo = photo.subsample(3,3)
    pLabel.configure(image = photo)
    pLabel.image = photo
    window.after( 10, zoom_out )

def keypress_Up(Event):
    global zooming
    zooming = True
    zoom_in()

def keypress_Down(Event):
    global zooming
    zooming = True
    zoom_out()

def keyrelease(Event):
    global zooming
    zooming = False

window.bind("<Up>",keypress_Up)
window.bind("<Down>",keypress_Down)
window.bind("<KeyRelease-Up>",keyrelease)
window.bind("<KeyRelease-Down>",keyrelease)
```